# Не передаются пользовательские поля в crm bitrix24

Tags: php, wordpress, битрикс24

Не могу найти в чем причина того что в лид не передаются пользовательские поля в bitrix 24. Передаю данные из worpress формы contact form 7. Все остальные поля успешно попадают в лид.

Код перехвата данных из формы в файле functions.php:

```
// Вызываем функцию для перехвата данных
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function');
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function($contact_form)
{
    // Перехватываем данные из Contact Form 7
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $posted_data = $contact_form->posted_data;
    if ($title) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        $queryUrl = 'https://visatour.bitrix24.ru/rest/58/xxxxxxxxxx/crm.lead.add.json';

        $fields = [];
        foreach ($posted_data as $key => $value) {

            if ($key == 'PHONE') { // номер телефона 
                $fields['fields']['PHONE'][0]['VALUE'] = $value;

            } else if ($key == 'EMAIL') { // емейл 
                $fields['fields']['EMAIL'][0]['VALUE'] = $value;

            } else if ($key == 'TOWN') { // город 
                $fields['fields']['UF_CRM_1588341571425'] = $value;

            } else if ($key == 'COUNTRY') { // страна посещения 
                $fields['fields']['UF_CRM_1588341622622'] = $value;

            } else if (($key == 'GOALTRAVEL') || ($key == 'goal-tour')) { // цель поездки 
                $fields['fields']['UF_CRM_1588341641812'] = $value;

            } else if ($key == 'TYPEVISA') { // тип визы 
                $fields['fields']['UF_CRM_1588509673435'] = $value;

            } else if ($key == 'COUNT') { // число виз 
                $fields['fields']['UF_CRM_1588509835065'] = $value;

            } else if ($key == 'DATE') { // дата посещения страны 
                $fields['fields']['UF_CRM_1588509979719'] = $value;

            } else {
                $fields['fields'][$key] = $value;

            }
        }

        $fields['params'] = ["REGISTER_SONET_EVENT" => "Y"];
        $fields['fields']['TITLE'] = $title;
        $fields['fields']['SOURCE_ID'] = 'WEB';
        $fields['fields']['ASSIGNED_BY_ID'] = '34';
        $fields['fields']['STATUS_ID'] = 'NEW';

        $queryData = http_build_query($fields);

        // Обращаемся к Битрикс24 при помощи функции curl_exec
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array(
            $curl,
            [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_URL => $queryUrl,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
            ]
        );
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $result = json_decode($result, 1);
        if (array_key_exists('error', $result)) echo "Ошибка при сохранении лида: " . $result['error_description'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что эти дополнительные поля созданы именно для лида. Попробуйте через консоль проверить, добавятся ли эти данные. Выведите где-нибудь получающийся массив и посмотрите все ли там есть. А еще лучше используйте php библиотеку CRest от самого Битрикс24. С ней проще и удобнее.